# New site (small) UI glitch

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As I have to meet some crazy quality standard, I need to write a nice line here which is obviously a burden for me to write and for you to read.

[image]

Comment: Looking into this now

Comment: Reported here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/121

Answer (score 3):

I believe this was caused by text zoom greater than 1:1. I put in a fix on dev, should be on production in the next build(Sometimes later tonight or tomorrow).

Comment: Your diag is right. Re-checking I found that zooming to a different value of 100% (either more or less) causes this